# StringBuffer and append method

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

Does the following slow the performance of `append` method and how many String objects are created in the `append` ?

```
long[] numbers = new long[20];

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(20);

for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {

    result.append(numbers[i] + " ");

}
System.out.println(result);
```

I mean if Strings are immutable, the append method should create one for `numbers[i]` then another one for the space `" "`, combine them into a a final one and garbage collect the two ? Am I wrong ? Is the plus sign an overkill here or should I use the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {

    result.append(numbers[i]);
    result.append(" ");
}
```

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question :). Second snippet is definitely the way to go.

Comment: The latter would be better :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version will actually get compiled into something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {

    result.append( new StringBuilder(numbers[i]).append(" ").toString() );

}
```

so you can see we are creating a whole new `StringBuilder` at each iteration then throwing it away.

so your second version is much better since it will only use 1 StringBuffer.

I would also recommend that you use a `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` since `StringBuffers` synchronize and you appear to only be using it in a single thread.

Comment: + for showing the resulting compiled code (i was to slow with my answer) and + for recommend to use StringBuilder with focus that StringBuffer are syncronize

Answer (score 1):

The first one is slower.  Any time you create a new object and then have to garbage collect it, it's going to add some overhead and slow your system down.  The second one is faster -- maybe not a lot but it is faster -- and I'd use it myself instead of the first.